# How to configure nginx http image filter module?

Tags: nginx

I have two servers and need to configure nginx http_image_filter module.

First server config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name image.site.com;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-error.log;


  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.4;
    }
}
```

And config on 192.168.1.4 is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name image.site.com;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-error.log;
  root /home/zulu/img/RU/;

location ~ "/img/RU/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)x([0-9]+).png$" {
  set $image $1;
  set $width $2;
  set $height $3;
  image_filter resize $width $height;
  }
}
```

It's not working when I go to image.site.com/img/RU/image.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is right config:

Proxy

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name image.site.com;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/image.site.com.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.151.4;
    }

    proxy_cache images;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_valid 30d;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating;
    expires 30d;
}
```

And image server

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name image.site.com;
  access_log      /var/log/nginx/image.site.com.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/image.site.com-error.log;
  root /var/www/files/update/ServiceLogo/;
  image_filter_buffer 50M;

  location ~ ^/(?<width>\d+)x(?<height>\d+)/(?<name>.*)$ {
    image_filter resize $width $height;
    alias /var/www/files/update/ServiceLogo/$name;
  }

  location ~ ^/c/(?<width>\d+)x(?<height>\d+)/(?<name>.*)$ {
    image_filter crop $width $height;
    alias /var/www/files/update/ServiceLogo/$name;
  }

  location ~ ^/users/(?<width>\d+)x(?<height>\d+)/(?<name>.*)$ {
    image_filter resize $width $height;
    alias /var/www/files/update/personDocs/$name;
  }

  location ~ ^/cusers/(?<width>\d+)x(?<height>\d+)/(?<name>.*)$ {
    image_filter crop $width $height;
    alias /var/www/files/update/personDocs/$name;
  }

}
```